# named pipe stream example not showing the result

Tags: c#, namedpipeserverstream

I'm new to pipe stream and tried to practice. I've written the following two projects and I can't see the result (which I wrote within the server project) from the client project. Here's the first project:

```
using (NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("test-pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message))
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello, it's me!\n");
    namedPipeServer.WaitForConnection();
    Console.WriteLine("A client has connected!");
    namedPipeServer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Here's the second project:

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "test-pipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
{
    namedPipeClient.Connect();
    namedPipeClient.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
    string serverResponse = string.Empty;
    byte[] readBytes = new byte[5];
    while (!namedPipeClient.IsMessageComplete)
    {
        namedPipeClient.Read(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);
        serverResponse = Encoding.Default.GetString(readBytes);
        readBytes = new byte[5];
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine(serverResponse);
    byte[] writeBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello from client!\n");
    namedPipeClient.Write(writeBytes, 0, writeBytes.Length);
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236), and consider [edit]ing the question to describe the problem. For example a title of "Named pipe stream fails to *something*", and the question describing what actually happens, and what you expect to happen. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Richardissimo I'm sorry, I don't come to stackoverflow that often

Comment: There's no problem, I'm just trying to help you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client doesn't receive any message from the server, because `namedPipeClient.IsMessageComplete` must be called **after** read operation. See [PipeStream.IsMessageComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipestream.ismessagecomplete?view=netframework-4.7.2) on docs:

> Gets a value indicating whether there is more data in the message
>   returned **from the most recent read operation**.

Otherwise `namedPipeClient.IsMessageComplete` returns `true` and code inside `while`-loop is not executed. So you have to rewrite `while` loop to `do-while` loop to ensure, that read operation occurs before `namedPipeClient.IsMessageComplete` is tested.

But there are more problems, see comments for explanations:

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "test-pipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
{
    namedPipeClient.Connect();
    namedPipeClient.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;

    // StringBuilder is more efficient for string concatenation
    StringBuilder serverResponse = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] readBytes = new byte[5];

    do
    {
        // You need to store number of bytes read from pipe (to readCount variable).
        // It can be less then the length of readBytes buffer, in which case
        // GetString() would decode characters beyond end of message.
        var readCount = namedPipeClient.Read(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);
        var readText = Encoding.Default.GetString(readBytes, 0, readCount);

        // You original code "overwrites" content of serverResponse variable instead
        // of concatenating it to the previous value. So you would receive only 
        // the last part of the server message.
        serverResponse.Append(readText);

        // It is not needed to create new buffer, you can just reuse existing buffer
        //readBytes = new byte[5];

    // IsMessageComplete is now tested after read operation
    } while (!namedPipeClient.IsMessageComplete);

    System.Console.WriteLine(serverResponse.ToString());

    // You current server implementation exits as soon as it sends message to the client
    // and does not wait for incomming message. You'll have to change server accordingly 
    // to be able to send a message back to the server.
    //byte[] writeBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello from client!\n");
    //namedPipeClient.Write(writeBytes, 0, writeBytes.Length);
}
```

---

#### EDIT:

When named pipe is in the `PipeTransmissionMode.Message` mode, every call of `NamedPipeServerStream.Write()` on the server sends data through the pipe as an individual message. Client can then receive these messages separated from each other
(as opposed to `PipeTransmissionMode.Byte` mode, where client receives just single continuous stream of bytes, no matter how many writes server performed using `NamedPipeServerStream.Write()`).

When client reads data from pipe (`namedPipeClient.Read()`), method is allowed to return less data then requested (for example when there is not enough space in the receiving buffer to store the whole message, or message is shorter then the requested number of bytes), see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipestream.read?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> Returns the total number of bytes that are read into buffer. **This
>   might be less than the number of bytes requested** if that number of
>   bytes is not currently available, or 0 if the end of the stream is
>   reached.

You can then use `namedPipeClient.IsMessageComplete` and `readCount` to detect this. Let me explain it on some example: Imagine that server sends message `ABCDEFGHIJKL` to the client, encoded to byte array as `{ 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76 }`. This message has length of 12 bytes, thus it does not fit to your receiving buffer (`readBytes`) which is 5 bytes long. So when client reads from pipe for the first time using `namedPipeClient.Read()`, receiving buffer will contain just first 5 bytes (`{ 65, 66, 67, 68, 69 }` corresponding to `ABCDE`) of the message. And this is where `namedPipeClient.IsMessageComplete` will help us, because it will return `false` indicating that we didn't receive complete message, there are still some bytes left and we should continue reading.

The second read from the pipe will be similar, we will read second part of the message (`{ 70, 71, 72, 73, 74 }` corresponding to `FGHIJ`), `namedPipeClient.IsMessageComplete` is still `false` indicating incomplete message.

When third read from the pipe comletes, only 2 remaining bytes (`{ 75, 76 }` corresponding to `KL`) will be read, but our buffer is still 5 bytes long, so it will look like this: (`{ 75, 76, 72, 73, 74 }` corresponding to `KLHIJ`). Values `72, 73, 74` are still there from previous iteration of the loop. And now it is important to store value returned from `namedPipeClient.Read()` to the `readCount` variable. It will contain value 2, indicating that only 2 bytes of the `bytesRead` buffer are valid and the remaining bytes should be ignored.

Comment: @Nuf What does IsMessageComplete do? I don't really understand the MSDN doc. Also, why do we need to the readCount variable. What data does it really store? btw, thank you very much

Comment: @Marc2001 I added explanation to the answer.

Comment: Dude! You're the most awesome person I met on the internet. Thanks alot! You really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to user `StreamReader` for reading messages from both pipes. 
Server:

```
using (NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("test-pipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte))
{
    namedPipeServer.WaitForConnection();
    Console.WriteLine("A client has connected!");

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello, it's me!\n");
    namedPipeServer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    namedPipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();

    var reader = new StreamReader(namedPipeServer);
    var msg = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Client:

```
using (NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "test-pipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
{
    namedPipeClient.Connect();

    var reader = new StreamReader(namedPipeClient);
    var msg = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(msg);

    byte[] writeBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello from client!\n");
    namedPipeClient.Write(writeBytes, 0, writeBytes.Length);
    namedPipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();
}
```